# How to change color of text inside setError method?

Tags: android

I am currently using an Android application where I am using the `setError` method for `EditText` validation. The problem is that I want to change the color of the text inside the method.

```
 EditText UserNameEdt, PasswordEdt;
 String UserName;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.login);
     UserName = UserNameEdt.getText().toString();
     Password = PasswordEdt.getText().toString();

     if (UserName.equals("")) {
         UserNameEdt.setError("Enter UserName");    
     } 
 }
```

I want to change the color of string "enter username" into black, not the text inside the EditText.

Answer (score 13):

Error text with app theme color:

```
UserNameEdt.setError("Enter UserName");
```

You can use an HTML tag to change text color. Set like below:

```
UserNameEdt.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'>hello</font>"));
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
UserNameEdt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```