# setError (put precise text color)

Tags: android

I need specify a precise color (#8ae234) to setError:

```
editText2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8ae234"));
editText2.setError("ERROR");
```

which didnt helped me to do what i need.It shows the old colour instead of new.

Comment: Define `does not run`.

Comment: I see old color (original template color)

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17269203/1777090) helps.